# Newtonsoft json converter - Cannot serialize an all attributes of an overridden class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I wrote a little example that explains my problem.

I have main class: `MainClass`

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And I have leaf class: `LeafClass`

```
public class LeafClass : MainClass
{
    public string ID2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #region Constructor
    public LeafClass(MainClass oMainClass)
    {
        this.ID = oMainClass.ID;
        this.ID2 = "my 2nd ID";
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In my main:

```
MainClass MC = new MainClass();
LeafClass[] LF = {new LeafClass(MC), new LeafClass(MC)};
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
serializer.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.KeyValuePairConverter());
string JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LF, serializer.Converters.ToArray());
```

I don't have my ID2 in my Json, I have only the base attributes. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What is `Leaf`? Please provide a [correct example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Wait... how is LeafClass able to access this.ID at all??

Comment: I forgot to override...

Comment: Still, what is new Leaf()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to solve my problem.

I had to add this decorator on the LeafClass `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` and `[JsonProperty]`on each property.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class LeafClass : MainClass
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ID2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #region Constructor
    public LeafClass(MainClass oMainClass)
    {
        this.ID = oMainClass.ID;
        this.ID2 = "my 2nd ID";
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MainClass
...

[Serializable]
public class LeafClass : MainClass
...
```

Edited...

You are passing in an instance of MainClass that has never set ID, yet you are assigning ID to that value.  ID is null.

```
public LeafClass(MainClass oMainClass)
{
    this.ID = oMainClass.ID;  // <-- oMainClass.ID is null because you never set it in oMainClass
    this.ID2 = "my 2nd ID";
}
```

try this:

```
MainClass MC = new MainClass();
MC.ID = "ABC";
LeafClass[] LF = { new LeafClass(MC), new LeafClass(MC) };
```